# $\frac{1}{x}f(x) = xf(\frac{1}{x})$ and $f(x+y)+1 = f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Determine all $ f \colon \mathbb{R}\to  \mathbb{R} $ such that 
$\frac{1}{x}f(x) = xf(\frac{1}{x})$ and $f(x+y)+1 = f(x)+f(y)$

Comment: What have you tried? What functions can you guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-1$. Then by the second condition,
$$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y). $$
It is well know that this implies $g(ax)=ag(x)$ whenever $a\in\Bbb Q$, so here
$$ f(ax)=af(x)-a+1.$$
In case $a:=x^2$ is a positive rational, we conclude from the first condition
$$ xf(\tfrac 1x)=\frac 1xf(x)=\frac1xf(x^2\cdot\tfrac 1x)=\frac1x\left(x^2f(\tfrac1x)-x^2+1\right)=xf(\tfrac1x)-x+\frac 1x$$
and therefore $x=\frac 1x$, which is absurd.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $ g(x) = f(x) - 1$, then $ g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.